# MySQL Union query taking too much time to execute

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm trying to get a single MySQL query result from different queries working on different table and databases, this is my table structure with database names:

database `ads1`-
tables: `clicks_214`,`requests`

database `ads2`-
tables: `clicks_255`,`requests`

database `ads3`- tables: `clicks_256`,`requests`

and this is the query which I'm trying to execute

```
$query="";
for($i=1;$i<4;++$i)
{
    $this->db_num=$i;
    $this->selectDB($i);
    $table=$this->getTableName();
    $db=$this->getDatabaseName();
    $query.="(SELECT r.kwd, count(c.rid) as cnum, count(r.kwd) as rnum
            FROM $db.requests r LEFT JOIN $db.$table c ON r.id=c.rid
            WHERE hid='$hid' 
            AND r.time BETWEEN '$date1 $hour1:00:00' AND '$date2 $hour2:59:59'
            GROUP BY r.kwd
            ORDER BY cnum DESC
            LIMIT $limit,50)";
    if($i<3)
    {
        $query.=" UNION ";
    }
}
```

I'm certainly sure that this isn't the best way to do it, just because I have to wait about 5 minutes to get results. Is there any way to do this much faster? I've already set indexes on all of the 3 DBs

this is an EXPLAIN result:
[image]

Comment: Where does hid come from? Also, dare I ask why you have multiple databases and tables?

Comment: Hid come from another table which is used only to compare requests. I have multiple databases and table because the amount of data records is massive, but the tables structure is the same; the only difference between different databases is the "click" table, which, as you can see, it changes name for each database ($table variable)

Comment: Can you execute the query in a MySQL window and post an EXPLAIN?

Comment: Did you look at partitioning?

Comment: @Strawberry never heard about that :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a) You SHOULD NOT make such crossdatabase queries. With your DB structure it would be more appropriate to run 3 independent queries and combine the result using some simple script Or to make a temporary table in one of the databases where you can combine data from every one of those

b) On large databases put some indexes to improve the speed. It is not the solution though...

You can try to play with Temp tables:

```
$this->selectDB('temptableDB');
$maketemp = "
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_table_1 (
  `kwd` int ,
  `rid` int,
)
"; 

mysql_query($maketemp, $connection) or die ("Sql error : ".mysql_error());

for($i=1;$i<4;++$i)
{
   $this->db_num=$i;
   $this->selectDB($i);
   $table=$this->getTableName();
   $db=$this->getDatabaseName();

   $inserttemp = "
    INSERT INTO temptableDB.temp_table_1
     (`kwd`, `rid`)
        SELECT r.kwd, c.rid
        FROM $db.requests r LEFT JOIN $db.$table c ON r.id=c.rid
        WHERE hid='$hid' 
        AND r.time BETWEEN '$date1 $hour1:00:00' AND '$date2 $hour2:59:59'
  ";

  mysql_query($inserttemp, $connection) or die ("Sql error : ".mysql_error());

 }

  $select = "
    SELECT kwd, count(rid) as cnum, count(kwd) as rnum
    FROM temp_table_1
    GROUP BY r.kwd
    ORDER BY cnum DESC
  ";
  $export = mysql_query($select, $connection) or die ("Sql error : ".mysql_error());
```

Comment: I've already set indexes, same for all databases, and it has improved from 15 minutes to 5 minutes the execution time... However, I know mine idea isn't the best, but i was only trying to speed it up, you think that a temp_table should improve performance?

Comment: From my experience - yes. TEMP table will allow you to create a middle layer and optimize a query. Firstly you will make a database appropriate for making such aggregating query you require and afterwards you just group the data.